# Proper bool definition as non-nullable operator

Tags: c#

```
var account = new TRANSPORT_TO_ACCOUNT
{
    TransportLayerId = reader["ID"] as string,
    ...
    BLOCKED = reader["BLOCKED"] as bool,
};
accounts.Add(account);
```

I've had a problem with this code.

> The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('bool' is a non-nullable value type)

How should I declare the `BLOCKED` properly in this case?

Comment: What is `reader`? if it is some derivate of `DbDataReader` it has a `GetBoolean()` and an `IsDbNull()`  method you could use.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure the property is a `bool`, then just cast it:

```
var account = new TRANSPORT_TO_ACCOUNT
              { TransportLayerId = (string)reader["ID"]
              , BLOCKED = (bool)reader["BLOCKED"]
              };

accounts.Add(account);
```

Or if you are not sure is has a value or not:

```
, BLOCKED = (bool?)reader["BLOCKED"]
```

Or if you are not even sure it is a (nullable) boolean field:

```
, BLOCKED = reader["BLOCKED"] as bool?
```

And if reader is a `DbDataReader`, you could use `GetBoolean`, as [Rene Vogt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528593/ren%C3%A9-vogt) suggested.

As a side note: you should work on your naming conventions. Properties and classes should be camel cases, so it would be `Blocked` and `TransportToAccount`.

Comment: Note that the first version (`(bool)reader.[...]`) will throw an exception if the value is `null`.

Comment: Agreed, but than it is not a `bool`, which I stated as requirement and also can be read from the question.

Answer (score 2):

If your `reader` is some derivate of `DbDataReader` (for example a `SqlDataReader`) you could use `IsDbNull()` and `GetBoolean()`:

```
int blockedIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("BLOCKED");
var account = new TRANSPORT_TO_ACCOUNT
{
    TransportLayerId = reader["ID"] as string,
    ...
    BLOCKED = reader.IsDbNull(blockedIndex) 
                ? (bool?)null 
                : reader.GetBoolean(blockedIndex)
};
accounts.Add(account);
```

Since `IsDbNull` and `GetBoolean` use the column index as parameter instead of the column name, you'd want to cache the index using `GetOrdinal` first.

And as [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373165/5528593) already suggested, try to improve your naming conventions.